# Only the button that is pressed should change color

Tags: javascript, css

Currently, after the play svg button is clicked, it changes all of them to one color at the same time.

How do I prevent that from happening? https://jsfiddle.net/qLjs6bz9/

Here are the play svgs

After I click 1 of them, then click the Home button which is the **X**

[image]

[image]

What ends up happening is all of the buttons change to 1 color at the same time.

[image]

Only the the play svg button I clicked on should change to a different color, **not all of them** at once.

How do I fix that in the code?

**CSS**

```
.newButtonColor1 .playa{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor2 .playb{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor3 .playc{
   fill: green;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.add("bg1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor2");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor3");
  }
```

**I also tried this:** https://jsfiddle.net/mhaj8pek/

**CSS**

```
.newButtonColor .playa{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor .playb{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor .playc{
   fill: green;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.add("bg1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor");
  }
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function showHidden() {
    const theHides = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    theHides.forEach(function needsAName(removeHide) {
      removeHide.classList.remove("hide");
    });

  }

  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.remove("bg1");
  }


  function showActive() {
    const theActive = document.querySelector(".with-curtain.active");
    theActive.classList.remove("active");
    showHidden();
    showBody();
  }

  function homeClickHandler() {
    showActive();
  }

  function addClickToHome(goHome) {
    goHome.forEach(function addHandler(goHome) {
      goHome.addEventListener("click", homeClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const goHome = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
    addClickToHome(goHome);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.add("bg1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor2");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor3");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
    showBody();
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

function combinePlayerOptions(options1 = {}, options2 = {}) {
  const combined = Object.assign({}, options1, options2);
  Object.keys(options1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
    if (typeof options1[prop] === "object") {
      combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, options1[prop], options2[prop]);
    }
  });
  return combined;
}

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createStopHandler(player) {
    const stopButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
    stopButtons.forEach(function addHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function stopHandler() {
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createStopHandler(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      onReady: onPlayerReady
    };

    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      enablejsapi: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer
  };

}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  managePlayer.add(".playa", {});

  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });

  manageUI.init({});

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1{
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}
body.bg1:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.newButtonColor1 .playa{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor2 .playb{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor3 .playc{
   fill: green;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.homesvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open" pointer-events="none">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="home">
            <title>Home</title>

            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#home" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#home" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you reduce it to a minimal reproducible example so it's easier/quicker for us to go through?

Comment: Everything is connected to each other, if I remove something from it, the code will fall apart.

Comment: The issue can be seen in both the snippet and jsfiddle I provided. https://jsfiddle.net/qLjs6bz9/

Comment: It's a lot of code, ngl. Whichever event listener that's fired when pressing the play button, pass the event, event.target.classList.add('played'), where played is your css class with desired color upon that button having been pressed.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.add("bg1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor1");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor2");
    theBody.classList.add("newButtonColor3");
  }
```

you're always adding all the three classes to the body, regardless of which button was clicked. Which has the expected consequences:

```
.newButtonColor1 .playa{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor2 .playb{
   fill: green;
}

.newButtonColor3 .playc{
   fill: green;
}
```

I personally would just remove the three `newButtonColor` classes from `showBody()`, and add something like this

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle("filled-with-green");
```

to `coverClickHandler()`.

Comment: What if I only want it to change to 1 color, and not back and forth between colors? https://jsfiddle.net/2j5xt1zf/ If I click on the same button a 2nd time, it changes back to the other color. How would I adjust that in the code?

Comment: Then instead of "toggle", "add".